# Generic adapter pattern in spring-cloud that will allow you pub/sub to different messaging services

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-jms, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-gcp, spring-cloud-bus

Is there a generic adapter pattern in spring-cloud that will allow you pub/sub a message?
Basically allowing you to the change provider type to ampq, kafka, pubsub or jms.
Business case is being able to change a pub/sub messaging service, avoiding cloud vendor lock-In.
A simple pub/sub unified generic framework.
Example code.

```
    PublisherBuilder builder = adapterFactory.getProvider("pubsub");
    Publisher publisher = builder.withProperties(properties).objectMapper(objectMapper);
    pubisher.publish(mesg);
```

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Stream does exactly that -- you swap out binders through dependency management.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream